# Open and Read a CSV File without libraries

Tags: python, csv

I have the following problem. I am supposed to open a CSV file (its an excel table) and read it without using any library.

I tried already a lot and have now the first row in a tuple and this in a list. But only the first line. The header. But no other row.

This is what I have so far.

```
with open(path, 'r+') as file:
    results=[]
    text = file.readline()
    while text != '':
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            a=line.split(',')
            b=tuple(a)
            results.append(b)
            return results
```

The output should: be every line in a tuple and all the tuples in  a list.

My question is now, how can I read the other lines in python?

I am really sorry, I am new to programming all together and so I have a real hard time finding my mistake.
Thank you very much in advance for helping me out!

Comment: you have wrong indentaiton and you use `return results` after you read first line so it doesn't read next lines.

Comment: you use `readline()` which reads only one line - better use `for line in file` - without  `readline` and without `while` loop. OR at least use `read()` instead of `readline()` to get all text which you later split to lines using `split('\n')`

Comment: some data may have one item in many lines and then `'\n'` shouldn't be treated as end of row. Similar problem can be with `,` - so better use module `csv` for this.

Comment: You are looking for wrong question. The problem you should solve is how you can use csv module, instead of how to parse csv file without any library. Considering of many edge cases like value containing line break, separate symbol; optional quoting, etc. The current answers below do not support full RFC4180 definition.

Comment: **Why** can't you use any library — is this homework?

Comment: mhh I also used read() instead of readline() but with the same result. The while loop right now doesn't do anything I think. So I could also leave it out. But I didn't realise that I treated '\n' as end of the line. I simply wanted to cut this part out. But I guess this is the wrong approach then. Thank you all very much for your advises. This helps a lot!

Comment: Yes it is homework. It was easy with the csv module but without it is quite hard -.-

Comment: In that case @furas's first two comments would likely fix your code. His third comment about it not handling items on a line with embedded newlines, and that using the `csv` module would avoid that problem is also true. While handling such cases yourself is possible with additional code, it that may not matter much for a relatively simple homework assignment…

Answer (score 0):

This problem was many times on Stackoverflow so you should find working code.

But much better is to use module `csv` for this.

---

You have wrong indentation and you use `return results` after reading first line so it exits function and it never try read other lines.

But after changing this there are still other problems so it still will not read next lines.

You use `readline()` so you read only first line and your loop will works all time with the same line - and maybe it will never ends because you never set `text = ''`

You should use `read()` to get all text which later you split to lines using `split("\n")` or you could use readlines() to get all lines as list and then you don't need `split()`. OR you can use `for line in file:` In all situations you don't need `while`

---

```
 def read_csv(path):

    with open(path, 'r+') as file:

        results = []

        text = file.read()

        for line in text.split('\n'):
            items = line.split(',')
            results.append(tuple(items))

        # after for-loop
        return results
```

---

```
def read_csv(path):

    with open(path, 'r+') as file:

        results = []

        lines = file.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') # remove `\n` at the end of line
            items = line.split(',')
            results.append(tuple(items))

        # after for-loop
        return results
```

---

```
def read_csv(path):

    with open(path, 'r+') as file:

        results = []

        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\n') # remove `\n` at the end of line
            items = line.split(',')
            results.append(tuple(items))

        # after for-loop
        return results
```

---

All this version will not work correctly if you will '\n' or `,` inside item which shouldn't be treated as end of row or as separtor between items. These items will be in `" "` which also can make problem to remove them. All these problem you can resolve using standard module `csv`.

Comment: unfortunately I am not allowed to use module csv. But thank you for the freindly advise :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty well and you are near goal:

```
with open(path, 'r+') as file:
    results=[]
    text = file.read()
    #while text != '':
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        a=line.split(',')
        b=tuple(a)
        results.append(b)
    return results
```

Your Code:

```
with open(path, 'r+') as file:
    results=[]
    text = file.readline()
    while text != '':
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            a=line.split(',')
            b=tuple(a)
            results.append(b)
            return results
```

So enjoy learning :)

One caveat is that the csv may not end with a blank line as this would result in an ugly tuple at the end of the list like `('',)` (Which looks like a smiley)

To prevent this you have to check for empty lines: `if line != '':` after the `for` will do the trick.

Comment: thanks a lot! Yeah I already saw that 'smiley'. I will look for a way to treat empty lines differently. Is there a way force a new line after one of the tuples?

Comment: I have edited my answer regarding the filtering of newlines. But in assignments you can assume that csv don't have empty lines, neither in the middle nor in the end. The Assignment must say this explicitly. You can always argue that YAGNI is good style in programming.

Comment: @Irina if the this helped you please mark this as "answer" by hitting the checkmark near the Score ;)